# Visual Studio 2022 cmake project auto add header guards

Tags: visual-studio-2022

So I have decided to give Visual Studio 2022 a try instead of using CLion for a while. I've noticed that when I create a CMake project in VS, in the Solutions Explorer I'm missing the option to "Add Class"([picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0vxy.png)). If I create a different type of project, the option is there. Having to manually add `.cpp`/`.h` files for each class w/o a template is a drag. How do I go about this?

Another thing is, the default template for new header files is `#pragma once`, while in CLion it's `#IFNDEF` guards; afaik the second one is more versatile, is it possible to have a template for them in VS2022?

Comment: Use `#pragma once` and forget about guards. Also generating a solution is currently better than using embedded CMake support. Solutions are much better supported by the MSVS and plugins.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.